# How to get the first value in mysqli_fetch_array php

Tags: php, while-loop, mysqli

I have this code where am able to perfectly get all values from the database using php mysqli_fetch_array with while loop

```
    $pid = 1;                                             
    $sqlSI = "SELECT * FROM productcolor where proId='$pid'";
    $SIresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlSI);
        
    if (mysqli_num_rows($SIresult) == 1) {
        echo ' <h4>Color</h4>
        <div class="colors">';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($SIresult)) {
            ?>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="s-colors" data-color="<?= $row['colors']; ?>" style="background-color: <?= $row['colors']; ?>;"></a>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".pdt-color-cart").val("<?= $row['colors']; ?>");
            })
        </script>

<?php
        }
        echo ' </div>';
    }
    else if (mysqli_num_rows($SIresult) > 1) {
        
        $rowed = mysqli_fetch_array($SIresult);
        echo $rowed['colors'];

        echo ' <h4>Color</h4>
        <div class="colors">';
        
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($SIresult)) {
            
            ?>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="s-colors" data-color="<?= $row['colors']; ?>" style="background-color: <?= $row['colors']; ?>;"></a>

<?php
        }
        echo ' </div>';
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
    

?>
```

In the code above I did one where if the value is `1` then do this else if it is `more than 1` then still do this.

But what I want is that while it is doing the **> 1** loop, I want to be able to still grab one value out of it - especially the first value that will come out.

How do you do it?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure precisely what you mean by " want to be able to still grab one value out of it". In your current code, it appears that `$rowed = mysqli_fetch_array($SIresult);` would cover that requirement, if I've understood correctly - this line always gets the first row of the results. So in that case, what specifically is the problem you're having? Because it appears the code would already do what you want it to.

Comment: @ADyson when i do that, let me say that there are three values that was fetched and i used the $rowed then it will only return two values in the $row and one in $rowed, i don't want it like that

Comment: @ADyson `mysqli_fetch_array()` will move the internal pointer to the second row. When the `while` loop starts it will iterate from the second row onwards.

Comment: @Dharman yes I know that. I was trying to clarify whether or not that's what the OP was intending (or indeed what they were intending precisely. I found the question wording unclear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task can be achieved easier if you tidy up your code a little bit. Instead of mixing the database logic with presentation logic, simply fetch the data before you start outputting your HTML/JavaScript. You can store the number of elements in a variable.

```
// Fetch the data and store it in an array
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM productcolor where proId=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $pid);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$no_of_elements = count($data);

// If more than one element present in the results
if ($no_of_elements > 1) {
    echo $data[0]['colors'];
}

echo ' <h4>Color</h4>
<div class="colors">';
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo <<<S_COLORS_BLOCK
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="s-colors" data-color="{$row['colors']}" style="background-color: {$row['colors']};"></a>
    S_COLORS_BLOCK;
}

// If only one element is present then display JavaScript
if ($no_of_elements === 1) {
    echo '
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".pdt-color-cart").val('.json_encode($row['colors']).');
        })
    </script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to "remember" what the first color that pops out is? In that case you could have a variable set before the first if, something like $saveColor = TRUE. Then inside the elseif, check $saveColor, if TRUE, change it to FALSE and also set a 2nd variable to save the color, like

```
$firstColorFound = $rowed['colors'];
```

or something like that.

Next time it loops, $saveColor won't be TRUE anymore, and thus $firstColorFound won't be overwritten. Hope that helped!